# Using CSS can I check if a browser supports the "CSS Properties and Values API" (Houdini) @property rule

Tags: css, browser-support, css-houdini

With some browsers starting to introduce the [CSS Houdini API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Houdini), I was wondering if there were any ways to identify if the [CSS Properties and Values API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Properties_and_Values_API/guide) is supported with CSS alone?

With Javascript I'm able to check if the API exists: ✅

```js
typeof window.CSS.registerProperty !== 'undefined'
```

Are there any equivalences native to CSS? I was experimenting with the [@support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) rule, but this only accepts properties and values -- not 'at-rules'. So the following will understandably **not** work. ❌

```css
@property --my-color {
  syntax: '<color>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: #c0ffee;
}

@supports ( @property : --my-color ) {
  body { background:DarkSeaGreen ; }
}

@supports not ( @property : --my-color ) {
  body { background:Crimson; }
}
```

☝️ [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/marknotton/pen/rNzeyQZ?editors=0100)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently best we can do at this point is to pretend that support of `paint` worklet denotes support of CSS Typed OM `@property` in style sheets: unlike `@property`, `<property-accepting-image>: paint(<ident>)` can be used in `@supports` block.

Una Kravets uses this in her [@property dev.to article](https://web.dev/at-property/):

```
@supports (background: paint(something)) {
  /* [Typed OM `@property` should be supported here] */
}
```

She also notes that this is (was) not reliable in Chromiums from version 78 up to v84.

For current state of browsers according https://ishoudinireadyyet.com/ it should be safe to use this recommendation:

[image: ishoudinireadyyet.com table showing that all browsers supporting the Paint API also supports CSS Typed OM]

It seems plausible that UAs newly adopting Houdini will release support for both paint API and CSS OM in style sheets, i.e. the Chromium v84 scenario will not happen again. (And if it will, my bet is the Typed OM will be released prior to paint worklet, so the condition will be (unnecessarily) ignored in that versions.)

Answer (score 3):

### Firefox's Support = <s>TBC</s> Experimental

I guess `paint(...)` will be far from Firefox's supports, but Firefox is already doing some [experimental supports on CSS Properties and Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Experimental_features) via `layout.css.property-and-value-api.enabled` and `layout.css.properties-and-values.enabled`.

#### `layout.css.property-and-value-api.enabled`

- It is documented in [MDN Web Doc: Experimental features in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Experimental_features)
- It is not implemented in Firefox 116 (Stable) ... Firefox 118 etc.

#### `layout.css.properties-and-values.enabled`

- It can be turned to `true` in `about:config` to get `window.CSS.registerProperty` being supported.
- It does not really mean you can use `@property`.
- Using `typeof window.CSS.registerProperty !== 'undefined'` is not guaranteed to have the support on `@property`.

[image]

- **Note: Starting from Firefox 120, it is truly supported**

### CSS Detection

#### No `@supports` for `@property`

There is no `@supports (@property) {...}`.

You can use pure CSS or JavaScript to detect this feature is supported or not. (For pure CSS, it can just display the text to tell you it is not supported.)

#### Pure CSS Detection via Pseudo Element's content

- Set a number property `--num` with initial value above 0. (number 3)
- Use `counter` and `counter-style` to generate the support message with number 3 and unsupported message with number 0.

```css
@property --my-color {
  syntax: '<color>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: #c0ffee;
}

@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 3;
  inherits: false;
}

@counter-style my-style-fallback {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols: 'Not Supported''Not Supported';
}

@counter-style my-style {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols: 'Supported''Supported';
  range: 2 4;
  fallback: my-style-fallback;
}

#result-css {
  counter-set: num var(--num);
}

#result-css::after {
  content: 'Not Supported';
  content: counter(num, my-style);
}
```

### JavaScript Detection

#### No try catch block with `CSS.registerProperty`

- Note: At the time I write this post, it is still not handled correctly in Chrome.

The following code

```js
window.CSS.registerProperty({
  name: "--my-color",
  syntax: "<color>",
  inherits: false,
  initialValue: "#c0ffee",
});
```

***might*** not raise any error if you have defined the property via CSS not via JavaScript.

Note: If you use `registerProperty` to register the property name that defined in CSS, then error might come and at the same time the property is being override.

[image]

#### Detection by `getComputedStyle`

Since every CSS properties are well defined with type and initial value, you can use `getComputedStyle` API to check it.

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--my-color');
```

In your case, the result shall be `"#c0ffee"`.
If it is not defined, the result will be `""`.

### Combined Coding Demo for Reference

#### [jsFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/lunarlogic489/xtb8que7/5/)

```js
const resultByJs = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--my-color');


document.getElementById('result-js').textContent = resultByJs === '' ? 'Not Supported' : 'Supported'
```

```css
@property --my-color {
  syntax: '<color>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: #c0ffee;
}

@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 3;
  inherits: false;
}

@counter-style my-style-fallback {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols: 'Not Supported''Not Supported';
}

@counter-style my-style {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols: 'Supported''Supported';
  range: 2 4;
  fallback: my-style-fallback;
}

#result-css {
  counter-set: num var(--num);
}

#result-css::after {
  content: 'Not Supported';
  content: counter(num, my-style);
}
```

```html
<html>


<div>
  <h3>`@property` checking by CSS</h3>
  Result: <span id="result-css"></span>
</div>


<div>
  <h3>`@property` checking by JS</h3>
  Result: <span id="result-js"></span>
</div>


</html>
```

### Remarks added on 2023/12/15

It has been tested that, Firefox 120 (Stable) can enable CSS Houdini using `layout.css.properties-and-values.enabled = true`

However, it is still not yet supported with Animation API.

Further Remarks: The support starts from Firefox Nightly 123.0a1 (2023-12-30) (64-bit)

Further Remarks: The stable support starts from Firefox 123.0 since 2024.03.02

#### [jsFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/lunarlogic489/kx8joawb/1/)

```js
const resultByJs = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--my-color');


document.getElementById('result-js').textContent = resultByJs === '' ? 'Not Supported' : 'Supported'


document.documentElement.animate(
  [
    { '--num': '100' },
    { '--num': '0' }
  ],
  {
    fill: "forwards",
    duration: 1000*30,
    easing: 'linear'
  }
);

let resultByJsA = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--num');

document.getElementById('result-jsa').textContent = `${resultByJsA}`.length > 1 ? 'Supported' : 'Not Supported';
```

```css
@property --my-color {
  syntax: '<color>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: #c0ffee;
}

@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 3;
  inherits: false;
}


@counter-style my-style-fallback {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols: 'Not Supported''Not Supported';
}

@counter-style my-style {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols: 'Supported''Supported';
  range: 2 4;
  fallback: my-style-fallback;
}

#result-css {
  counter-set: num var(--num);
}

#result-css::after {
  content: 'Not Supported';
  content: counter(num, my-style);
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block; width: 18em;
}
```

```html
<html>


  <div>
    <h3>`@property` checking by CSS</h3>
    Result: <span id="result-css"></span>
  </div>


  <div>
    <h3>`@property` checking by JS</h3>
    Result: <span id="result-js"></span>
  </div>
  
  
  <div>
    <h3> Animating `@property` checking by JS</h3>
    Result: <span id="result-jsa"></span>
  </div>


</html>
```

Comment: A great rundown and detailed answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `window.CSS.paintWorklet` to check houdini api is supported or not.